# Custom language associations in VS Code based on the contents of the first line

Tags: visual-studio-code

Using VS Code (v1.39.2) when I open a file whose first line is `#!/bin/bash`, the editor knows to set the language to `Shell Script`. Is there a way that I can configure my own language associations such that some arbitrary first line is associated with a built-in language (e.g. `/bin/hello-world` selects `Perl`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `#!/bin/bash` part is called a shebang. I don't believe that VSCode supports custom shebangs by default but you can use the [Shebang Language Associator](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=davidhewitt.shebang-language-associator) to do what you want. You just enter its settings and set whichever pattern and language you want.

**Example**:

```
"shebang.associations": [
    {
        "pattern": "^#!/bin/bash$",
        "language": "shellscript"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Shebang Language Associator is great, however, you can configure language associations in the application. In the config file add:

```
    "files.associations": {
        "*.myphp": "php"
    }
```

or

```
    "languages": [{
        "id": "java",
        "extensions": [ ".java", ".jav" ],
        "aliases": [ "Java", "java" ]
    }]
```

Language supports are added using the language identifier:

```
    "grammars": [{
        "language": "groovy",
        "scopeName": "source.groovy",
        "path": "./syntaxes/Groovy.tmLanguage.json"
    }],
    "snippets": [{
        "language": "groovy",
        "path": "./snippets/groovy.json"
    }]
```

Hope this helps!